# c also has const values but they cannot be used as array bounds?

Tags: c

In book "The Practice of Programming By Brian W. Kernighan, Rob Pike", Page 21, the buttom of expert "Define numbers as constants, not macros", he says "C also has const values but they connot be used as array bounds, so the enum statement remains the method of choice in C.

but it conflict with my practice:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void) 
    {
        const int bound = 5;
        int array[bound];

        return (0);
    }
```

it can pass through compiling.

Comment: And what year was your edition of that book published in? Also, `int main(void)` is a poor practice. And why have you omitted the `bound` type?

Comment: `int main(void)` is not  poor practice.  Well defined in C99 and C11

Comment: @chux It may be well defined, but it looks lazy to me. Why not include the `int, char **` or even `int, char **, char **`?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` may look less lazy to some but would not add to OP's post.  Posts are best when they are minimal.  `int main(void)` is legal C and focuses the problem on `const bound = 5; int array[bound];`

Comment: @chux it was a comment. And OP mentioned "practice"... also dropping the type from `bound` (while legal in K&R) looks lazy (to me).

Comment: @Elliott Frisch  Agree that not using `int` (or some explicit type) in `const bound = 5;` is poor practice.

Comment: I am sorry, the statement "const bound = 5" is wrong typed, it should be "const int bound = 5"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` variables are not actually constant. Thats the reason that before C99 you are not allowed to do

```
const int bound = 5;
int array[bound];
```

C99 introduces variable length arrays which allows the above declaration.

Comment: but once you declare a `const` variable, it cannot be assign again.

Comment: `const` qualifier to a variable just implies that the variable can't be modified. It doesn't mean that it is constant. A variable is a variable!

Answer (score 4):

> C also has const values but they connot be used as array bounds

Although this statement has been true for K&R C and ANSI C, C99 standard has introduced variable-length arrays, making your declaration valid (and their statement about usability of `const` in array declarations invalid).

With C99-compliant compiler you could use any expression of integral type, not even a const one, to declare the size of an array:

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
if (n <= 0) {
    printf("Invalid array size.\n");
    return -1;
}
int array[n]; // <<== This is allowed in C99
```

**Note:** Your example uses an old rule of C by which variables without an explicit type declaration were considered `int`. A modern (as in "for the last twenty+ years") declaration of `bound` should look like this:

```
const int bound = 5;
//    ^^^
```

Comment: Are you still allowed to infer `int` types in C99? I thought that was K&R only...

Comment: I get a warning when I compile about missing type specifier, but it compiles

Comment: i forgot write int in the statement 'const bound = 5' :(

Answer (score 1):

You are using C99.

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an
>   extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++. These arrays are
>   declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a length that is
>   not a constant expression. The storage is allocated at the point of
>   declaration and deallocated when the block scope containing the
>   declaration exits.

```
float read_and_process(int n)
{
    float vals[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        vals[i] = read_val();
    return process(vals, n);
}
```